# Can we use DFT to compute the potential energy of dynamic processes?

Tags: density-functional-theory

Suppose we want to determine the potential energy between a hydrogen atom and a surface, such as Cu(001), during hydrogen scattering on Cu(001) surface, assuming that the hydrogen atom does not change the surface structure.

I used DFT to perform single-point calculations to find the potential energy at various heights of the hydrogen atom above the surface. The potential energy was calculated using the equation:
$$
E_{potential} = E_{H+surface} - E_{H} - E_{surface}
$$
The results looked like

[image]

The question then arises: is the method outlined above reliable for computing the H-surface potential energy? Can DFT accurately calculate the potential energy of such dynamical processes?